# Reg-ex to validate a sting with digits only but all Zeros are not allowed

Tags: regex

I am validating a String, new to regex and not really able to figure out how to validate it with certain rules.

Rules:
1. Must contain only digits.
2. Max length can be upto 5.
3. Minimum length allowed is 1 but this string must have only non-zero digit.
4. Preceding zeros are allowed but all the digits must not be zero.

Comment: 5. Do my work for me.

Comment: If string size is 5, then isn't that also the minimum length?

Comment: @HåkenLid: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? It would be simpler to split the validation up. `^\d{1,5}$` and not `^0*$`.

Comment: @Zenoo: 6. Thanks for the kind words but I am really stuck.

Comment: `^(?!0+$)\d{1,5}$`?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far, then, we'll gladly help you.

Comment: @HåkenLid: I am doing this for JSON validation using Everit-json-schema.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @ctwheels: Worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SachinRohaj: you should state in the question what you want to use this for. Not all validation can be done with a single regular expression, and Everit-json-schema supports writing custom validator classes. Also not all regex dialects support variable length lookaheads like in ctwheels solution, so you have to say which programming language you are using.

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mLOyiU/2)

```
^(?!0+$)\d{1,5}$
```

---

### Results

Results as described by the header for the section.

```
** VALID **
1
12345
00001
01
10

** INVALID **
0
00000
123456
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!0+$)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not `0` one or more times, followed by the end of the line
- `\d{1,5}` Any digit between 1 and 5 times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line